# Automated test using appium, protractor, android emulator. Error code 100

Tags: android, protractor, appium

Hi i am having a problem when i run the test. I am receiving error code 100 but I can't found the problem. I was thinking that maybe is the configuration but I tried with diferent things and the result is allways the same. I am using this configuration. Any idea?

conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    platformName: 'android',
    autowebview: true,
    platformVersion: '5.1',
    deviceName: 'Nexus 5X API 25',
    app: '..../android-debug.apk',
    browserName: '',
    },
  baseUrl: 'localhost:5554',
  specs: ['spec-2.js'],
  onPrepare: function () {
        var wd = require('wd'),
            protractor = require('protractor'),
            wdBridge = require('wd-bridge')(protractor, wd);
        wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);
    }
};
```

log :

```
I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[09:40:06] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
[09:40:11] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[09:40:13] E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Invalid timeout 'script'
    at WebDriverError (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:440:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(11000)
    at WebDriver.schedule (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:816:17)
    at Timeouts._scheduleCommand (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1500:25)
    at Timeouts.setScriptTimeout (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1483:17)
    at browser_.ready.browser_.ready.then.then (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:281:49)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1366:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2953:27)
    at asyncRun (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2813:27)
    at C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:676:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
[09:40:13] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Comment: Is the selenium server running on the http://localhost:4723/wd/hub ? Protractor throws this error most of the time when you havent started webdriver-manager

Comment: yes is running.

TCP    127.0.0.1:4723         127.0.0.1:53018        ESTABLISHED